# How to manage multiple classes in C#? (Duplication)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class

Simple question. I am writing an application in VS 2010 C# for fun (Learning experience) and I don't know how to get around a problem in an acceptable way.

Lets say I have a class called "Biscuit"

```
class Biscuit
{
    private string Brand = String.Empty;
    private string Variant = String.Empty;

    public void CreateBiscuit(string pBrand, string pVariant)
    {
        Brand = pBrand;
        Variant = pVariant;
    }

    public void GetDetails(ref string pBrand, ref string pVariant)
    {
        pBrand = Brand;
        pVariant = Variant;
    }
}
```

The user can create as many instances of this object as they want. All they have to do is give a brand and variant. I then create the object and store it in a list

Problem is, I don't want there to be duplicates. So no two objects where both the Brand and Variant are the same as another instance .

I could loop through all objects in the BiscuitLibrary, but this doesn't seem like good practice, or good performance. (Current Code Below)

```
    List<Biscuit> BiscuitLibrary = new List<Biscuit>();

    public void CheckDuplicate(string pBrand, string pVariant)
    {
        string ObjectBrand = String.Empty
        string ObjectVariant = String.Empty;

        foreach (Biscuit CurrentItem in BiscuitLibrary)
        {
            CurrentItem.GetDetails(ref ObjectBrand, ref ObjectVariant);

            if ((ObjectBrand == pBrand) && (ObjectVariant == pVariant))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This Biscuit Already Exists, Sorry!");
            }
            else
            {
                Biscuit NewBiscuit = new Biscuit();

                NewBiscuit.CreateBiscuit(pBrand, pVariant);

                BiscuitLibrary.Add(NewBiscuit);
            }

        }
    }
```

How should I do this?

Thanks, Tom!

Comment: Since your code already works, I think you need a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Remove that`ref` stuff, and use proper LINQ.

Comment: My name isn't Tom, but you're welcome.

Comment: I didn't know there was a code review site, that sounds useful!. I am pretty new much new to C# from VB.NET, never heard of HashSet and never used LINQ. But ill have a look at them. Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe a static collections containing Brands and Variants?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best practice would be to store all instances in a HashSet instead of a List. This would be especially useful for performance if you planned to store thousands of instances. Going through each of them in a List and checking for duplicates would be an expensive operation. While HashSet organizes its contents based on object hash codes in a way that allows very efficient duplicate checks. You can read more about HashSet here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397727(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397727%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Before HashSet can be used, you have to prepare your class by overriding its GetHashCode() and Equals() methods:

```
class Biscuit
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Variant { get; set; }

    public Biscuit(string brand, string variant)
    {
        Brand = brand;
        Variant = variant;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || typeof(Biscuit) != obj.GetType())
            return false;

        Biscuit biscuitObj = obj as Biscuit;

        return biscuitObj.Brand == this.Brand && biscuitObj.Variant == this.Variant;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + this.Brand.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + this.Variant.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }   
}
```

Now you can use this class with a HashSet:

```
//we create a HashSet and add 4 biscuits to it
//one of the biscuits is duplicate and will not be inserted
var uniqueBiscuitBox = new HashSet<Bisquit>();
uniqueBiscuitBox.Add(new Biscuit("A", "1"));
uniqueBiscuitBox.Add(new Biscuit("A", "1"));
uniqueBiscuitBox.Add(new Biscuit("B", "1"));
uniqueBiscuitBox.Add(new Biscuit("C", "4"));
Console.WriteLine(uniqueBiscuitBox.Count()); //returns 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already using something similar to a Factory pattern you could do some modifications of your code tom make it work as you want to:

```
class Biscuit
{
    // You should use properties
    public string Brand {get; private set;}
    public string Variant {get; private set;}

    // Use a protected constructor so it can't be used outside the class
    protected Biscuit(string brand, string variant)
    {
        Brand = brand;
        Variant = variant;
    }

    // Use a static list to hold the already crated biscuits
    private static List<Biscuit> _existingBiscuits = new List<Biscuit>();

    // "Factory method" to create Biscuit instances
    public static Biscuit CreateBiscuit(string pBrand, string pVariant)
    {
        // Use LINQ to find if there are any biscuits already crated with the brand and variant 
        if (_existingBiscuits.Any(b => b.Brand == pBrand && b.Variant == pVariant))
        {
            // If the biscuit already exist return null, no biscuit created
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            // Create biscuit and add it to the list
            var biscuit = new Biscuit(pBrand, pVariant);
            _existingBiscuits.Add(biscuit);

            return biscuit; 
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion: require instances be constructed with valid data; throw if the user tries to pass invalid data and avoid the “construct then initialize” antipattern.

```
public class Biscuit : IEquatable<Biscuit>
{
    public string Brand { get; private set; }
    public string Variant { get; private set; }

    public Biscuit(string brand, string variant)
    {
        if (brand == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("brand");
        if (variant == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("variant");
        Brand = brand;
        Variant = variant;
    }

    public bool Equals(Biscuit b)
    {
        if (b == null) return false;
        return string.Equals(Brand, b.Brand, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
               && string.Equals(Variant, b.Variant, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

If you want a list with special rules (e.g. no two items have the same Brand and Variant) then create a class that implements the rules. Do not use generic lists and try to enforce rules at runtime.

Copying @SoftwareFactor's idea, you can create strongly-typed `HashSet`s with an `IEqualityComparer`:

```
class BiscuitEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Biscuit>
{
    public bool Equals(Biscuit b1, Biscuit b2)
    {
        if (b1 == null) return b2 == null;
        return b1.Equals(b2);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Biscuit b)
    {
        if (b == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("b");
        return b.Brand.GetHashCode() ^ b.Variant.GetHashCode();
    }
}


var bh = new HashSet<Biscuit>(new BiscuitEqualityComparer());
bh.Add(new Biscuit("Alpha", "Beta"));
bh.Add(new Biscuit("Alpha", "Gamma"));
bh.Add(new Biscuit("Alpha", "Beta"));    // will not be added.
```